# Creating a UITableView for app settings with a large number of static rows

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am creating a UITableView for my app settings programmatically.

The TableView contains of a large number of static rows, each with a different lay-out and with different UIControls. Currently, I have created a UITableViewCell for each row individually, ending up with a very large ammount of UITableViewCell classes. I find it confusing to handle so many UITableViewCell definitions and these cannot be considered as "dequeueReusableCell's" since they are only used once.

Since some of these class definitions do not differ significantly (for example only a UISwich instead of a UIButton), I was wondering whether it could be implemented in a different way and to reduce the number of UITableViewCell definitions.

I already considered inappsettingskit, but it appears not suitable for some rows and I also prefer to write the code by myself.

Comment: So what's your question? You already figured you could extract the common parts of your cells.

Comment: My question is how to reduce the number of class defintions or whether a different approach is possible. For example, would it be possible to peform all the layout in a single class (i.e. the cells are not reusable anyway)?